# SQL Left Join Decreasing Performance

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

I was updating a report and was adding some data to a temp table using multiple left joins

```
CREATE TABLE #tSD(
                PLCY00ID int,
                CLSBSNS varchar(max),
                ACTSD decimal(5,2),
                NSWSD decimal(5,2),
                NTSD decimal(5,2),
                QLDSD decimal(5,2),
                SASD decimal(5,2),
                TASSD decimal(5,2),
                VICSD decimal(5,2),
                WASD decimal(5,2),
                OSSD decimal(5,2),
                NSWSDEx Varchar(250)
                )


INSERT INTO #tSD
SELECT PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID,
    CLSBSNS=n100432.STRNGSMLVL,
    ACTSD=n100420.DCMLVL,       
    NSWSD=n100421.DCMLVL,   
    NTSD=n100422.DCMLVL,
    QLDSD=n100423.DCMLVL,
    SASD=n100424.DCMLVL,
    TASSD=n100425.DCMLVL,
    VICSD=n100426.DCMLVL,
    WASD=n100427.DCMLVL,
    OSSD=n100428.DCMLVL,
    NSWSDEx=Null--n100922.STRNGSMLVL
FROM @tPLCYS p
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100432 ON n100432.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100432.LMNT00ID=100432    
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100420 ON n100420.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100420.LMNT00ID=100420
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100421 ON n100421.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100421.LMNT00ID=100421
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100422 ON n100422.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100422.LMNT00ID=100422
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100423 ON n100423.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100423.LMNT00ID=100423
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100424 ON n100424.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100424.LMNT00ID=100424
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100425 ON n100425.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100425.LMNT00ID=100425
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100426 ON n100426.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100426.LMNT00ID=100426
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100427 ON n100427.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100427.LMNT00ID=100427
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100428 ON n100428.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100428.LMNT00ID=100428
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100922 ON n100922.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100922.LMNT00ID=100922
```

After I added the above the time required to run on a sample data increased from 3 seconds to 5 minutes.
When I removed the insert and ran as a select only, the report ran for seconds again. I wasn't getting any duplication of rows.

I then decided to split the left joins into individual queries. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tSD(
                PLCY00ID int,
                CLSBSNS varchar(max),
                ACTSD decimal(5,2),
                NSWSD decimal(5,2),
                NTSD decimal(5,2),
                QLDSD decimal(5,2),
                SASD decimal(5,2),
                TASSD decimal(5,2),
                VICSD decimal(5,2),
                WASD decimal(5,2),
                OSSD decimal(5,2),
                NSWSDEx Varchar(250)
                )

-- Class of Business
INSERT INTO #tSD
SELECT PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID,
    CLSBSNS=n100432.STRNGSMLVL,
    ACTSD=Null,     
    NSWSD=Null, 
    NTSD=Null,
    QLDSD=Null,
    SASD=Null,
    TASSD=Null,
    VICSD=Null,
    WASD=Null,
    OSSD=Null,
    NSWSDEx=Null
FROM @tPLCYS p
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100432 ON n100432.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100432.LMNT00ID=100432    


UPDATE #tSD
SET ACTSD=n100420.DCMLVL
FROM @tPLCYS p
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100420 ON n100420.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100420.LMNT00ID=100420


UPDATE #tSD
SET NSWSD=n100421.DCMLVL
FROM @tPLCYS p
LEFT JOIN UC06DNDVLS0 n100421 ON n100421.PLCY00ID=p.PLCY00ID AND n100421.LMNT00ID=100421
```

After I did the above the got improved to the seconds again.

I'm just trying to understand what might have happened.

Execution plan
2 minutes
[image]

15 seconds
[image]

Comment: Please tag your database.

Comment: @Camus . . . You would need to look at the execution plans for the different queries.

Comment: I'm not very familiar on how to analyze the execution plan but I'll have a go. Thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the execution plan. Would you be able to assist me in reading it?